# Is it Possible to start the HSQL DB in file mode and keep that file inside Project

Tags: java, junit, hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am using HSQL DB in memory mode and created tables,data for junit purpose.
its working fine.Since it in memory mode the db instance destoyed once the all the junits are done.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb</property>
```

But i thought to switch the HSQL DB server mode from in memory to file instance .SO that i am thinking i can have all the schema and data which is written in file.

Kindly help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered making a [backup](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_online_backup) of in-mem db before exit and trying to restore on start?

Comment: @Fildor  exactly .Instead of loading everytime .Load once with file and use it for junit in development phase

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `file:` database.

There is an option to store the schema and the initial data in a `file:` database and open this database for tests with the `files_readonly=true` connection property. This avoids writing the changes to the original database.

See the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_db_file_mem